# What does DeprecationWarning mean when running Python

Tags: python, deprecation-warning

I ran a Python program and got a `DeprecationWarning`, like:

```
D:\programs\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\deprecation.py:70: DeprecationWarning: Function log_multivariate_normal_density is deprecated; The function log_multivariate_normal_density is deprecated in 0.18 and will be removed in 0.20. 
  warnings.warn(msg, category=DeprecationWarning)
```

I can't confirm what is wrong about it. What is a `DeprecationWarning`?

Comment: Did you try reading the warning text? (If you don't know the meaning of the word "deprecated", you could simply look it up.)

Comment: The function log_multivariate_normal_density is deprecated in 0.18 and will be removed in 0.20. It is just what the warning says

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general developers are developing libraries and in developing sometime add o change thing and sometime remove theme. removing is danger because user may used that and if a developer want to remove a thing first have to notify others to don't use this feature or things and after this he can remove. and DeprecationWarning is this notification.

Comment: ok, I know; thank you! it means now I can use this but this will be removed in next version(0.2here),yes?

Comment: perhaps yes. usually it will be removes as soon as possible.